# .htaccess rewrite with GET param

Tags: .htaccess

Im trying to transfrom link like this:
    `http://localhost/photohosting/user/view.php?img=60`
Into something like that in users browser:
    `http://localhost/photohosting/60`
Here my code for .htacces
    `RewriteEngine on`
    `RewriteRule ^view.php(.*)$ /photohosting/user/view.php?img=$1  [L,QSA]`
I'm not familiar with .htaccess so I can't found the mistake. Why this code doesn't work?
UPDATE: I've updated my .htaccess to:
    `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user/view.php?img=$1` and now link like `http://localhost/photohosting/60` works, but it misses param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following rule:

```
RewriteRule photohosting/([0-9]+)$ /photohosting/user/view.php?img=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: No, `localhost/photohosting/60` still not found

Comment: No, same result: 404 error. Maybe it`s important - .htaccess is in the root folder (in localhost/photohosting).